sum and merge different data in looker studio from third party called "Supermetrics"
I am trying to sum/merge 3 columns from different data sources in looker studio.
The data source provider is called "Supermetric" which is a thirdparty software provider to collect ads data from different social media
The data source add into looker studio are TikTok ads, google ads, and Facebook ads (those 3 are provided by Supermetric)
I want to see a sum of "impression" which is available in all those data sources but some how blending and create a calculated field doesn't work and indicate "no data" in a number chart I am making.

Looker studio report snapshot I am working on summing 3 columns
I try blending data into one new source and create a new calculated field by adding all those
data blending configuration[
number chart I am trying to sum all those impressions](https://i.sstatic.net/YtER5Lx7.png)
